# Camel - Multiple types of Consumer

Tags: web-services, rest, activemq-classic, apache-camel, routes

Am currently developing a Service which will be running separately. I want to make the service available for users in multiple formats. That is users can access the service by

1. Making a rest call
2. Making a Web Service
3. Publish in to a Queue
4. Upload a file

Is there a way , which I can provide this using Camel. i.e Can camel stand in front of all of these , and provide the routing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each consumer interface (file, jms, http, cxf, rest, etc) would require its own route, but each route can then call a common route to reuse the processing logic...

```
//first, define your interface routes to expose endpoint and convert data to common format as necessary
from("jms:...")...to("direct:processRequest");
from("cxf:...")...to("direct:processRequest");
from("jetty:...")...to("direct:processRequest");
from("file:...")...to("direct:processRequest");

//now define your common processing route
from("direct:processRequest")...
```

Comment: And if the service is running locally you can have from("jms:...")...to("bean:...), from("cxf:...")...to("bean:...) etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you! I proceeded with Tomcat -ActiveMQ example. Now, I have a WEB app running listening to tomcat routed by Camel. I tried adding Spring REST controller, to it but dont know how to route it. I want to route it when , the spring rest URL is called. How to do it? any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this with Camel. There are plenty of components that shall help you exposing service using different protocols. In your case you shall need jetty component to start an http endpoint, further a CXF Bean that shall serve the REST requests. Use spring webservices to expose a web service endpoint.  Look at the ready made examples available on apache's site : [camel-examples](http://camel.apache.org/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks! But all those example are for Only one type. Either one of those, ActiveMQ, Rest . Not all together

Comment: @madhairsilence You can combine them and have multiple routes in your application